# How to select all result from one column that stores many numbers by comma

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in MySQL, like below:

```sql
------------------------
    id    |    codes
------------------------
     1    |   1,2,3,4
------------------------
     2    |    1,4
------------------------
     3    |    1,2,4
------------------------
     4    |    1
------------------------
```

- Example-1: select all case that `codes` column contains 1 and 4, then the result is below (because the id=4 row that `codes` column not contain 4):

```sql
------------------------
    id    |    codes
------------------------
     1    |   1,2,3,4
------------------------
     2    |    1,4
------------------------
     3    |    1,2,4
------------------------
```

- Example-2: select all case that `codes` column contains 2 or 3, then the result is below (because the id=4, id=2 rows that `codes` column not contain any value in 2,3):

```sql
------------------------
    id    |    codes
------------------------
     1    |   1,2,3,4
------------------------
     3    |    1,2,4
------------------------
```

**Question:** But I don't how to write sql to do that if codes stores lots of value such as `1,2,3,..20,21`.

I tried this:

```sql
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table WHERE 
codes like '%1%4%' 
and codes REGEXP'[2|3]';
```

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: try `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store multiple values in a string column!  Do not store numbers as string!  Declare foreign key relationships!

Comment: @ Devsi Odedra : if use `FIND_IN_SET` ,then will be the below case:
```sql
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table WHERE 
codes like '%1%4%' 
and (codes find_in_set(2,codes) or find_in_set(3,codes))
```
if code have more values then the sql will be too long

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff: yes i agree with you. But Is there adivice for data model.If the I have Ten thousand rows,and the code has 20 more value?